# Can we apply the transaction scope for entire API actions on 1 request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API and EntityFramework 6.2. A scheduler will invoke the API for each customerID. For one request API will perform the 10 Actions.
 Now any one of the action gets failed these 10 actions should be rollback for that particular request.

Comment: A transaction scope deals with *database* transactions. It has no concept of HTTP calls.

Comment: My question is in API request on 1 customerID 10 different database actions will perform. Due to an exception, one action failed then it should revert the previously performed actions

Comment: The question is wrong. There aren't just 10 database actions, these are 10 different database connections, with 10 different transactions executing 10 different commands. Unless you implement a distributed transaction protocol, there's no way to get 10 different HTTP calls under the same transaction. That was no different back in the SOAP days. The exception back then was that there *was* a standard for distributed transactions, which didn't scale. There's no such standard for REST

Comment: I strongly suggest you read [Distributed transactions aren’t, and microservices still don’t mix](https://ayende.com/blog/186945-C/distributed-transactions-arent-and-microservices-still-dont-mix). It covers *exactly* what you ask and explains why it's wrong.

Comment: If you want a batch of requests to be finalized only after all of them are received, you'll have to implement this yourself - store the requests in some temporary storage and actually make any modifications only when the final request arrives. This means that you need to add a call that says `Start batch`, a way to correlate all actions (typically with a batch ID) and a final `Finish Batch` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single Controller method that takes a list of CustomerIDs this is trivial.  Just call a method like:

```
static void DoStuffToCustomers(List<int> customerIds)
{
    using (var db = new Db())
    using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (var id in customerIds)
        {
            db.DoStuffToCustomer(id);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

If you have 10 seperate HTTP requests, it's not advisable to even try.